# Mi programa en PHP no agrega datos a mi base de datos

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy aprendiendo PHP y MYSQL, y en un libro me pasan este código, que se supone debe crear una tabla y agregar unos datos a una base datos; cuándo lo abro solo crea la tabla pero no le agrega los datos, cuál creen que pueda ser el problema:

```
<?php
require_once 'login.php';
$connection = new mysqli($hn,$un,$pw,$db);

if($connection->connect_error) die("Fatal Error s");

$query = "CREATE TABLE users(
        forename VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
        surname  VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
        username VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
        password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
        )";

$result = $connection->query($query);
if(!$result) die("Fatal Error 2");

$forename = 'Bill';
$surname  = 'Smith';
$usernmae = 'bsmith';
$password = 'mysecret';
$hash     = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

add_user($connection, $forename, $surname, $username, $hash);

$forename = 'Pauline';
$surname  = 'Jones';
$usernmae = 'pjones';
$password = 'acrobat';
$hash     = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

add_user($connection, $forename, $surname, $username, $hash);

function add_user($connection, $fn, $sn, $un, $pw)
{
    $stmt = $connection->prepare('INSERT INTO users VALUES(?,?,?,?)');
    $stmt->bind_param('ssss', $fn, $sn, $un, $pw);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

El problema es un error en el cuarto parámetro que estás pasando en las dos llamadas que haces a `add_user()`:

```
add_user($connection, $forename, $surname, $username, $hash);
                                                ^ERROR: Variable no existe
```

La variable `$username` **no existe**, porque, sin duda por error, la has llamado: `$usernmae`. Significa entonces que `add_user` estaría recibiendo, en el mejor de los casos un valor `NULL`. Pero resulta que en la tabla, esa columna ha sido declarada como `NOT NULL UNIQUE`.

Puedes resolver este problema, definiendo la variable correctamente:

```
$username = 'bsmith';
```

Y,

```
$username = 'pjones';
```

### Recomendación

Escribe de forma explícita los nombres de columna en las consultas `INSERT INTO`. Si en un futuro la tabla `user` evoluciona (se le agrega o quita una columna), la consulta actual fallará. Esto es particularmente complicado en aplicaciones en producción o en aplicaciones grandes. Código como este dificulta el mantenimiento y deja las aplicaciones expuestas a graves fallos. ¿El motivo? La pereza de no escribir consultas explícitas. Si escribes tu consulta indicando las columnas de forma explícita, este trozo de código no fallará nunca y te asegurará que **siempre esos datos se insertarán en esas columnas**.

```
$stmt = $connection->prepare('INSERT INTO users (forname,surname,username,password) VALUES(?,?,?,?)');
```

Comment: Gracias amigo! Y seguiré tu recomendación.